# Conditional slicing in Scala Breeze

Tags: scala, breeze

I try to slice a `DenseVector` based on a elementwise boolean condition on another `DenseVector`:

```
  import breeze.linalg.DenseVector
  val x = DenseVector(1.0,2.0,3.0)
  val y = DenseVector(10.0,20,0,30.0)

  // I want a new DenseVector containing all elements of y where x > 1.5
  // i.e. I want DenseVector(20,0,30.0)
  val newy = y(x:>1.5) // does not give a DenseVector but a SliceVector
```

With Python/Numpy, I would just write `y[x>1.5]`

Comment: Read the Breeze API docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SliceVector resulting from `y(x:>1.5)` is just a view on the original `DenseVector`. To create a new `DenseVector`, use

```
val newy = y(x:>1.5).toDenseVector
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Breeze you have to use for comprehensions for filtering `DenseVector`s

```
val y = DenseVector(10.0,20,0,30.0)

val newY = for {
  v <- y
  if v > 1.5
} yield v

// or to write it in one line
val newY = for (v <- y if v > 1.5) yield v
```